$ \sup \{s_n + t_n : n > N\} \leq \sup \{s_n : n > N\} + \sup \{t_n : n > N\} $
$ \sup \{s_n + t_n : n > N\} \leq \sup \{s_n : n > N\} + \sup \{t_n : n > N\}   $
Both sequences are bounded, given in exercise
Consider set $A + B $
We know
$ \sup A+ B = \sup A + \sup B$
Take $$A = \{s_n : n > N\} $$
$$B= \{t_n : n > N\} $$
$$\{s_n + t_n : n > N\} \subseteq A + B $$. Because here terms are being added index wise and not every term is being added with every other as in case of $A+B$
$$ \sup \{s_n + t_n : n > N\} \leq \ supA + \ supB $$
I have doubt about this last step. Can you help ?
Thanks

your proof looks fine, the justification for ${s_n+t_n: n > N}\subseteq A+B$ could be better justified writing $A+B$ explicitly as ${s_n+t_m: n > N,m > N}$ and then picking $n=m$ gets us back to elements of our original set. Then it wouldn't hurt reminding that if $X\subseteq Y$, then $\sup(X) \leq \sup(Y)$. But those are details for being rigorous, the proof in itself is correct.

@rafilou2003 thanks..
